# Customize Calendar Event Reminder Icon

Tags: android, calendar, icons

does anyone know if there is a way to customize the Calendar Event Reminder Icon through code?

For example I'm currently working on a calendar app and would like to be able to distinguish the reminders placed there from my app from any other user events. Is it possible to highlight the whole cell? Or Change the size of the Icon from the stock Blue?

I have failed to find anything on here or Google.

Thanks for any info or directions.